# Map.change is not defined

Tags: dictionary, f#

I'm trying to invoke the [`Map.change`](https://fsharp.github.io/fsharp-core-docs/reference/fsharp-collections-mapmodule.html#change) function. It's clearly defined in the documentation but it just doesn't work for me. I've tried opening different namespaces (such as `FSharp.Core`, `Microsoft.FSharp.Collections`), with no success.

```
open FSharp.Collections

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv =
    let testMap = Map.empty.Add("test", true).Add("otherTest", false)

    let newTestMap = 
        testMap 
        |> Map.change // Here's the error!
                "otherTest" 
                (fun v -> 
                    match v with
                    | Some b -> Some (not b)
                    | None -> None )

    printf(newTestMap)
    0
```

I'm getting the following error when trying to run the sample code above:

`error FS0039: The value, constructor, namespace or type 'change' is not defined.`

How do I use `Map.change`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code works (apart from the `printf`). Maybe check your F# or .NET (Core) version. The Collections namespace doesn't have to be open.

```
let testMap = Map.empty.Add("test", true).Add("otherTest", false)

let newTestMap = 
    testMap 
    |> Map.change // Here's the error!
            "otherTest" 
            (fun v -> 
                match v with
                | Some b -> Some (not b)
                | None -> None )

printf "%A" newTestMap // map [("otherTest", true); ("test", true)]val it : unit = ()
```

[image: Map.change]

Comment: My version of `dotnet` was `3.1.402`, version of F#: `4.7`. After updating to `3.1.403` (which comes with F# `4.7` as well) I'm still getting the same error, `dotnet build` fails... What's your version of `dotnet`?

Comment: Ok I've tried running the same code in `dotnet fsi` - here I'm getting a warning saying `Experimental library feature, requires '--langversion:preview'. This warning can be disabled using '--nowarn:57' or '#nowarn "57"'.`. When I run the code from `dotnet fsi --langversion:preview` everything works fine. Thanks!

P.S. Why would the official documentation describe the preview features of the language by default without mentioning it is beyond my understanding...